# Expand Bootstrap accordions with URL

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap Collapse. I am trying to open a collapse automatically with the URL. For example I want to open the second collapse with page redirecting. If my URL is like this: `http://test.com/accordion.html#collapseOne` or
`http://test.com/accordion.html#collapseTwo`.

If I open this URL: `http://test.com/accordion.html#collapseThree`, the page should scroll to the target and expand the collapse, and close if there are any opened collapses. I have tried many ways, here is my code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var url = document.location.toString();
  if (url.match('#')) {
    var hash = url.split('#')[1];
    $('.card .collapse').removeClass('show');
    $('#' + hash + '_c').addClass('show');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne_c" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne_c" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Testing</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo_c" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
           Item #2
         </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo_c" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Testing</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree_c" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree_c" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Testing</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly note that you can get the fragment from the URL more simply by using `location.hash`. Secondly, you're appending `_c` to the Id you select in the jQuery object, yet this id does not exist in your HTML.

To do what you require you need to select the element directly and then call `collapse('show')` on it for it to be displayed.

In addition, you do not need to programmatically scroll the page as simply by including a fragment in the URL which matches the `id` of an element in the page the browser will scroll to that element automatically.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $(hash).collapse('show');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I've made a mistake, added the _c. But still, if I copy-paste http://test.com/accordion.html#collapseOne_c and the ID also to collapseOne_c. Working great. But it seems I cannot close the Collapse.

Comment: That behaviour should happen automatically as per the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/). I'd suggest starting a new question about it if you're having issues.